# DataGrid not updating when ItemsSource changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a class `AccountManager` that is implemented as a `Singleton class`:

```
namespace SampleApp.Manager
{
    public class AccountManager : INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static AccountManager Instance { get; } = new AccountManager();

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private List<Account> InternalAccounts { get; } = new List<Account>();

        public IReadOnlyCollection<Account> Accounts => InternalAccounts;

        private AccountManager()
        {

        }

        public void Add(Account account)
        {
            InternalAccounts.Add(account);

            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, account));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Accounts));
        }

        public void Remove(Account account)
        {
            if (InternalAccounts.Remove(account))
            {
                CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, account));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Accounts));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have `Page` where I want to work with these `Account` instances:

```
<Page x:Class="SampleApp.View.AccountView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mgr="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Manager"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignWidth="1200" d:DesignHeight="800"
      Title="AccountView">

    <Grid>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static mgr:AccountManager.Instance}, Path=Accounts.Count}" />

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static mgr:AccountManager.Instance}, Path=Accounts}">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property1" Binding="{Binding Property1, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property2" Binding="{Binding Property2, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property3" Binding="{Binding Property3, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property4" Binding="{Binding Property4, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I first tried to only trigger `AccountManager.CollectionChanged` to update the `DataGrid` in the view but that did nothing. So next I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and triggered `AccountManager.PropertyChanged` but that did not update the list but only the `TextBlock` containing the current number of items in `AccountManager.Accounts`.

This is just a stripped down version of what the classes actually look like so that's the reason why I don't use `ObservableCollection<T>` to do this, so please don't blame me for not using `ObservableCollection<T>`.

I would like to know what's wrong with my code? I don't understand why the `DataGrid` binding isn't getting updated but the `TextBlock` gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InternalAccounts` is a `List`, not an `ObservableCollection`. You never tell anybody that your list changed. Implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` on the viewmodel that owns it doesn't help the `List` raise any events: When the List changes, you do raise events saying that your viewmodel's *own* items changed, but it doesn't actually have any items -- its items are in the list, which is what the XAML is bound to.

If you make `InternalAccounts` an `ObservableCollection` and make `Accounts` `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`, that should fix it.

```
private OnlyObservableCollection<Account> _accounts = 
    new OnlyObservableCollection<Account>();

private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Account> _roAccounts;
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Account> Accounts
{
    get { 
        if (_roAccounts == null)
            _roAccounts = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Account>(_accounts);
        return _roAccounts;
    }
}
```

Internally, just add and remove stuff from `_accounts` and don't bother implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` on your viewmodel. You just got a full implementation for free, out of the box. This is much easier to do than you thought, which is always nice.